# How initialize a boolean matrix given true values on arrayTensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am a beginner in TensorFlow. I want to initialize a Boolean matrix with the indices of true values are given in an array varaibale.

Initial matrix (must be a tensor):
`[[False, False, False],
[False, False, False],
[False, False, False]]`

The given index array (must be a Tensor):

```
[1,3,5,6,8]
```

A result :

```
[[False, True, False],
[True, False, True],
[True, False, True]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code:

```python
import tensorflow as tf

f=tf.Variable([False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False])
t=tf.constant([True,True,True,True,True])

indice=tf.constant([1,3,5,6,8], dtype=tf.int32)

res_1D=tf.scatter_update(f, indice, t)

result_mat = tf.reshape(res_1D, shape=(3,3))

init=tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    result=sess.run(result_mat)

print(result)
```